# JavaFX Scene Builder 2 effects disabled

Tags: java, javafx

I cannot set effects as they are disabled

[image]

Anybody knows how to enable them? I have no problems using them in Scene Builder 1.1

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SceneBuilder 2 is currently early access software - not all features are implemented and some features have errors.  These shortcomings will be fixed over time with new releases of the software.

In the meantime if there is a feature you require which is not currently supported in SceneBuilder 2, either use SceneBuilder 1.1 or hand edit your FXML document.